# document.on("click","#myId", function(){} not working for updating owl carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, carousel, document

I am trying to use the [Carousel](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/images.html) example  and rewrite the function to support loading on click as follows ...

```
$(document).on("click","#myId",function(){
    $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
        autoPlay : 3000, //Set AutoPlay to 3 seconds
        items : 2,
        itemsDesktop : [1199,3],
        itemsDesktopSmall : [979,3]
    });
});
```

... so that I can use it in my webpage for toggle div as follows :

```
<div class="tabs clearfix">
  <ul>
    <li class="active"><a href="#01" id="myId" data-toggle="tab">2015</a></li>
    <li><a href="#02" id="myId" data-toggle="tab">2014</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="01">
    <div id="owl-demo">
      <div class="item"><img src="img/sample_1.jpg" alt="The Last of us"></div>
      <div class="item"><img src="img/sample_2.jpg" alt="GTA V"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="02">
    <div id="owl-demo">
      <div class="item"><img src="img/sample_1.jpg" alt="The Last of us"></div>
      <div class="item"><img src="img/sample_2.jpg" alt="GTA V"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to achieve something as shown below with different carousel of images on the right window on click on tab from the left window

[image: Sample Image]

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: `id` should be unique....If you need many, go for classes...

Comment: @RayonDabre tried it. didn't seem to help. the page loads fine for the first tab but when I click on another tab say "2014" all the images are displayed one after the other as a stack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be easier customize [these tabs](http://jsfiddle.net/syahrasi/us8uc/) instead of trying to write something from scratch. Just throw each carousel in it's respective tab container. Then initialize all of the carousels at the same time on page load. I don't see a need to reinitialize the whole plugin on each time your switch to a new tab. Your markup will look something like this:

```
<div id="tabs-container">
    <ul class="tabs-menu">
        <li class="current"><a href="#tab-1">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab-2">Tab 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab-3">Tab 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab-4">Tab 4</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab">
        <div id="tab-1" class="tab-content">
             <div id="owl-slider-1">
              <div class="item"><img src="img/sample_1.jpg" alt="The Last of us"></div>
              <div class="item"><img src="img/sample_2.jpg" alt="GTA V"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="tab-2" class="tab-content">
             <div id="owl-slider-2">
              <div class="item"><img src="img/sample_1.jpg" alt="The Last of us"></div>
              <div class="item"><img src="img/sample_2.jpg" alt="GTA V"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="tab-3" class="tab-content">
             <div id="owl-slider-3">
              <div class="item"><img src="img/sample_1.jpg" alt="The Last of us"></div>
              <div class="item"><img src="img/sample_2.jpg" alt="GTA V"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And your JS will look something like this:

```
(function () {

    $("#owl-slider-1").owlCarousel({
        autoPlay : 3000, //Set AutoPlay to 3 seconds
        items : 2,
        itemsDesktop : [1199,3],
        itemsDesktopSmall : [979,3]
    });

    $("#owl-slider-2").owlCarousel({
        autoPlay : 3000, //Set AutoPlay to 3 seconds
        items : 2,
        itemsDesktop : [1199,3],
        itemsDesktopSmall : [979,3]
    });

    $("#owl-slider-3").owlCarousel({
        autoPlay : 3000, //Set AutoPlay to 3 seconds
        items : 2,
        itemsDesktop : [1199,3],
        itemsDesktopSmall : [979,3]
    });

    $(".tabs-menu a").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().addClass("current");
        $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("current");
        var tab = $(this).attr("href");
        $(".tab-content").not(tab).css("display", "none");
        $(tab).fadeIn();
    });

})();
```

Obviously this code is completely untested but it should point you in the right direction.